PowerQuery connection to another excel file not retrieving entire table
I have one excel file that retrieves a list of transactions from another excel file.
Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("D:\Documents\Dashboard.xlsm"), null, true),
T_TRANSACTIONS_Table = Source{[Item="T_TRANSACTIONS",Kind="Table"]}[Data],

T_TRANSACTIONS contains a list of transactions that grows throughout the year, so the table gets longer as the year progresses. This has been working fine until recently, when I noticed that the connection was only retrieving transactions up through 7/1/2024, that's 2,495 transactions. This should be well within Excel's row limit. I've tried multiple refreshes and also tried recreating the entire query/connection from scratch, but the new connection still stops at the same point.
Note also there are no filters or other steps in the query that would limit results to a selected date range. I've also checked that the source table, T_TRANSACTIONS, includes all data, which it does.
Why is Excel not retrieving the entire table?
Input or suggestions appreciated.

I don't know what this issue was, but I've worked around it. I figured out that this issue was something in the original source table T_TRANSACTIONS. I have no idea what it was, but I copied the data (values only), deleted the table, and created the table again and copied back all the data, and reformatted it to look like the original table. After I did that, the connection worked just fine and pulled in all the data.
